# Finding one, not both results in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking to find numbers (with formatting, so no Regex) and the following code works:

```
Sub FindSuperscript()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim contentRange As Range
    Set contentRange = ActiveDocument.Content

    contentRange.Find.ClearFormatting

    With contentRange.Find.Font
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = False
        .StrikeThrough = False
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = False
        .Outline = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Hidden = False
        .SmallCaps = False
        .AllCaps = False
        .Superscript = True
        .Subscript = False
    End With

    With contentRange.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]*>"
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With

    contentRange.Find.Execute
    While contentRange.Find.Found
        contentRange.Find.Execute
    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

but it will find 10, and then 0 next when it should just find 10 and then find 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change a couple of things:

1. Make sure `.Wrap` is set to `wdFindStop` when looping. Otherwise it could go into an infinite loop (default is `wdFindContinue`).
2. `While...Wend` has been "deprecated" for a long time; preferred is `Do While/Until...Loop While/Until` which provides more flexibility in how it's set up.
3. When `Find` is successful the `Range` object that's being searched will be re-set to the found item. Therefore, it's necessary to move the search `Range` beyond that point. I prefer `Range.Collapse wdCollapseEnd` to move the starting point of the search beyond the previously found `Range`. (I'm not sure why using `Selection.MoveRight` is actually working when a `Range` is being searched as the selection should not be changing after "found"...)

Sample code:

```
With contentRange.Find
  .Text = "[0-9]*>"
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .MatchWildcards = True
End With

contentRange.Find.Execute
Do While contentRange.Find.Found
  contentRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  contentRange.Find.Execute
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Looks like you can use this:

`Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(contentRange.Text)`

So:

```
contentRange.Find.Execute
While contentRange.Find.Found
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(contentRange.Text)
    contentRange.Find.Execute
Wend
```

But interested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try something based on:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With .Font
      .Bold = False
      .Italic = False
      .StrikeThrough = False
      .DoubleStrikeThrough = False
      .Outline = False
      .Shadow = False
      .Hidden = False
      .SmallCaps = False
      .AllCaps = False
      .Superscript = True
    End With
    .Text = "<[0-9]@>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    MsgBox .Text
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As it's not apparent what you want to do with the found content, all I've put there is a message box.